# Less than 1 week to the first million questions on SO?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

On a rough average there about 1700 questions asked a day (992k / 2 years 2 months), if so that means about 5/6 days till 1 million, is that right it seems way too many :)

(less than a week that is if SO ever gets back online ;))

Comment: I think there should be a prize for whomever asks the millionth question. :O

Comment: Nah, too arbitrary. Besides, it can come and go several times if questions get deleted or migrated.

Comment: @Nathan Taylor I agree with Mark C but it would be fun to do something original to celebrate the occasion!

Comment: Its more suitable to celebrate the 1048576th question.

Comment: @Gamecat: why? ((2^10)^2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would have been fewer than 5/6 days even: you need to account for the ~linear growth in participation as per [Ian Elliots pretty good assumption](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4608/meta-raffle-when-will-stackoverflow-reach-one-million-questions/4613#4613) to [When Will StackOverflow Reach One Million Questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4608/meta-raffle-when-will-stackoverflow-reach-one-million-questions), so the current average is significantly higher already, more like ~2.4k/d from the top of my head.

Given this I'd been actually confident that my (late, hence easier) [own extrapolation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4608/meta-raffle-when-will-stackoverflow-reach-one-million-questions/63461#63461) could have been spot on by a thin margin eventually, but due to the current outage [ring0](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4608/meta-raffle-when-will-stackoverflow-reach-one-million-questions/62409#62409) is most likely in pole position for good already ;)

Comment: With the current maintenance, a little bit more time is needed to reach the millionth post :P